# I want to query all posts with ACF date field today and beyond

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm banging my head against the wall with this, is there anything wrong with my code?
I want to query all posts that have 'launch_date' today and beyond.

```
<?php

// find date time now
$date_now = date('M, d');

// query events
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 20,
    'post_type'         => 'project',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'relation'          => 'AND',
        array(      
            'key'           => 'launch_date',
            'compare'       => '<=',
            'value'         => $date_now,
            'type'          => 'DATETIME'
            )
    ),
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'          => 'launch_date',
    'meta_type'         => 'DATE'
);

echo build_query( $args );


?>
```

Comment: I'd recommend checking to make sure that your launch_date field is returning the date in the same date format you're checking against with your $date_now variable.

Comment: Especially considering $date_now is returning Right Now in the format "Sep, 20" as a string. You most likely would want to check against an all numerical date, and you need to include the year too in your check.

Comment: I would make the field return a unix time format, and compare with that. that way they are both integers and easylier comparable.